# Nonlinear control versus trajectory generation?

Tags: dynamical-systems, control-theory, optimal-control

I am a bit confused on the difference between nonlinear control(which seems to be focused on stabilizing system output with respect to a constant reference) versus trajectory generation to drive a dynamical system to a sequence of states.

Basically I want to understand the relationship between the two. In general what is the significance of stabilization control if your desire is trajectory generation? Can a stabilized system always track a desired reference signal?

Comment: Very often you can rewrite the tracking problem as the stabilization problem with respect to the tracking error signal.

Comment: On your second question: No, a stabilized system can not always track every desired reference signal. If that's possible depends also on the reference signal itself. A controller that can track constant signals can not necessarily also track ramps or quadratics.